# result of AJAX RSS Reader is uncertain

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, web

I use **AJAX RSS Reader** (follow [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_rss_reader.asp) link) to **read RSS** from my link:

```
http://vtv.vn/trong-nuoc.rss
```

My php file (**readRSS.php**):

```
<?php

$url = ("http://vtv.vn/trong-nuoc.rss");

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();

$xmlDoc->load($url);

$channel = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);

$channel_title = $channel->getElementsByTagName('title')
                ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

echo ($channel_title);

?>
```

And I got **different** results each time ajax call this php file (readRSS.php).

- Sometimes I got **correct** results:

```
    VTV - Trong nước - RSS Feed
```

- Sometimes I got **bad** results:

```
    Warning: DOMDocument::load(http://vtv.vn/trong-nuoc.rss): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in E:\xampp\htdocs\ajax\readRSS.php on line 14

    Warning: DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://vtv.vn/trong-nuoc.rss" in E:\xampp\htdocs\ajax\readRSS.php on line 14

    Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\ajax\readRSS.php on line 23
```

Please show me, how do I **always** get the **correct** results?

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you're not running from localhost?, it's literally getting a 404 response header which is likely vtv.vn itself

Answer (score 0):

You are literally getting a 404 Not Found error from the site. I doubt this is anything to do with you but you could:

Try getting the XML contents of the RSS file first:

```
$xml = file_get_contents("http://vtv.vn/trong-nuoc.rss");
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->loadXML($xml)
```

Comment: Your solution gives the same result as my solution. Thank you, but it has not solved my problem. Do you have another solutions?

Comment: Sorry, the problem is not the code, it's the target URL. vtv.vn intermittently throws a 404.